# DataBase NoSQL (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Hi I have the following problem: some of you have some NoSQL Data Base crowded, I've searched but still can not find some JSON to import, they are very grateful if anyone provide me with some database to test with MongoDB

Comment: Hablas ingles? [See this article on how to ask questions (ver este artículo sobre cómo hacer preguntas)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo provide a sample dataset which can be found [here](http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json). In addition there is documentation on [generating your own test data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/generate-test-data/).